# C# / AngularJS - Convert String into JSON

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, stored-procedures

I have a StoredProcedure, which generates a JSON string in my database.

```
{
    "menuTitleMobile": "Menu",
    "levels": [
                {
                "nav_type": "Sub",
                "level1_name":"Menu 1",
                "subitems": [
                    {
                    "level2_name": "Menu 1.1",
                    "level2_link": "#"
                    }, 
                    {
                    "level2_name": "Menu 1.2",
                    "level2_link": "#"
                    }]
                }
            ] }
```

I have created a C# Controller to access the Stored Procedure. In this controller I am trying to convert this String to a Json Object:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetDataMenu(string entity)
    {
        var da1 = new Models.data_access();
        var data1 = da1.GetDataMenu(entity);

        return new JsonNetResult(data1);

    }

    public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }

        public JsonNetResult(object data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {                
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data));                
        }
    }
}
```

But when I Access to this Method in my Angular App it shows me just one object with the whole string and not several objects (in example for the subitems)

```
function list ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://localhost:59964/Home/GetDataMenu",{
          params: {                  
              format: "json",
              contentType: "application/json",
              entity: ''                  
          }
      })
    .success(function(data) {           
        console.log(data);
    })};
```

Console:

```
[object Object]
   [
      0: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         Column1: "{
        "menuTitleMobile": "Menu",
        "levels": [
                    {
                    "nav_type": "Sub",
                    "level1_name":"Menu 1",
                    "subitems": [
                        {
                        "level2_name": "Menu 1.1",
                        "level2_link": "#"
                        }, 
                        {
                        "level2_name": "Menu 1.2",
                        "level2_link": "#"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
 },
      length: 1
   ]
```

How can i solve that it shows me the json file in the right way in my angular app ?

Comment: You could just return the string as the body of the response with the content type header set to `application/json`. None of this serialisation shenanigans

Comment: I tried it with the content type header, but still same result...

Comment: You are trying to serialize the row, not the column value. In any case, serializing to Json is needed if you *don't* already have a Json string - which you do. Just return the column text, eg `return data1.Column1;`

Comment: PS Web API already uses Json.Net so you don't need to create a `JsonNetResult` class. I suppose you have an ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: I'm more concerned why you have a *stored procedure generating JSON*.

Comment: @ Panagiotis - You're right. Just give back only the column text and Parse it in Angular and it works...